# PHP Regular Expression Exclusion

Tags: php, regex

Here is the sample PHP code:

```
<?php
$str = '10,000.1 $100,000.1';
$pattern = '/(?!\$)\d+(,\d{3})*\.?\d*/';
$replacement_str = 'Without$sign';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement_str, $str);?>
```

Target is to replace **numbers only** (i.e. "**$100,000.1**" should not be replaced). But the above code replaces both **10,000.1** and **$100,000.1**. How to achieve the exclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assertion is always true `(?!\$)\d+` as you match a digit which can not be a `$`

As the `.` and the digits at the end of the pattern are optional, it could also match ending on a dot like for example `0,000.`

Instead you can assert a whitespace boundary to the left, and optionally match a dot followed by 1 or more digits:

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Kbk6k/1)

Example:

```
$str = '10,000.1 $100,000.1';
$pattern = '/(?<!\S)\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\b/';
$replacement_str = 'Without$sign';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement_str, $str);
```

Output (If you remove the numbers, the text "Without$sign" is not correct)

```
Without$sign $100,000.1
```